# Excel formula XNPV input parameter (dates)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to call Excel formula in my program to get the XNPV value. The problem is what is the correct value to pass the "dates" parameter to the function? I have tried the formula ( =XNPV(2,{2,3},{"1/1/2020","1/2/2020"}) ) in Excel worksheet, and it return "#value".

```
Dim app = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim wf = app.WorksheetFunction
Dim list() As Integer = {1, 2, 3}
MsgBox(app.Evaluate("XNPV(2,{2,3},{""1/1/2020"",""1/2/2020""}"))
app.Quit()
```

Comment: Pass the "dates" as dates, not strings. In Excel, a date is a number. Replace "1/1/2020" with VALUE("1/1/2020").

Comment: Thanks @DS_London ! It is working now !!